# Error on Custom Dialog

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

> Hello and good luck to everyone.
>
> I am using Dialog in my application to show success when user orders
>   successfully.
>
> But I have encountered the error as shown. Dialog displaying
>   incorrectly with my custom in file.xml. Specifically in the xml I have
>   let the android property layout: `layout_width = "match_parent"` but
>   when displaying text is not enough to try to show)
>
> Who has a solution to help me? Sincerely thank.

**This is error:**

[image: This is img error]

**This is file.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_margin="32dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_done_all_black_24dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/OrderSuccessfully"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/img"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="@string/order_successfully_placed"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/thank"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/OrderSuccessfully"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:text="@string/thank_you"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnOrderSuccessfully"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/thank"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
        android:text="@string/ok"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.ButtonSignIn" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I suggest you change the text alignment to `center`. Otherwise, I think you will have to change the text size to get everything on one line.

Comment: thank you. i find right answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `LayoutParams` to `MATCH_PARENT` of your Dialog.

```
    Window window = dialog.getWindow();
    window.setLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

You can also use a custom `style` to customize your `dialog` property

```
<style name="CustomDialog" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowMinWidthMajor">90%</item>
    <item name="android:windowMinWidthMinor">90%</item>
</style>
```